# How to draw open-close interval in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following commands to have half-open interval in a real line:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.7,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/8,0.2/$S_1$,0.4/$T_4$,0.6/$S_3$,0.8/$T_2$,1/$S_3$,1.2/14,1.4/$S_3$,1.6/16}
    \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw (0.2,0.5pt) node[above] {$c$};
\draw[[-), ultra thick, blue] (0.2,.01) -- (.4,0.01);
\draw[(-, ultra thick, green] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, I need to have an open-close interval, but I am not able to have that close interval at the end, using the following command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.7,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/8,0.2/$S_1$,0.4/$T_4$,0.6/$S_3$,0.8/$T_2$,1/$S_3$,1.2/14,1.4/$S_3$,1.6/16}
    \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw (0.2,0.5pt) node[above] {$c$};
\draw[(-], ultra thick, green] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

May I ask for anybody help?

Answer (score 5):

When an optional argument contains closing brackets, use an extra pair of braces to "hide them"; otherwise, TeX thinks the closing bracket closes the optional argument. In this case, instead of

```
\draw[(-], ultra thick, green] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
```

use

```
\draw[{(-]}, ultra thick, green] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.7,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/8,0.2/$S_1$,0.4/$T_4$,0.6/$S_3$,0.8/$T_2$,1/$S_3$,1.2/14,1.4/$S_3$,1.6/16}
    \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw (0.2,0.5pt) node[above] {$c$};
\draw[{[-)}, ultra thick, blue] (0.2,.01) -- (.4,0.01);
\draw[(-, ultra thick, green] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.7,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/8,0.2/$S_1$,0.4/$T_4$,0.6/$S_3$,0.8/$T_2$,1/$S_3$,1.2/14,1.4/$S_3$,1.6/16}
    \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw (0.2,0.5pt) node[above] {$c$};
\draw[{(-]}, ultra thick, green] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `arrows.meta` library you can use the `Arc Barb` and `Bracket` arrow tips:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.7,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/8,0.2/$S_1$,0.4/$T_4$,0.6/$S_3$,0.8/$T_2$,1/$S_3$,1.2/14,1.4/$S_3$,1.6/16}
    \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw (0.2,0.5pt) node[above] {$c$};
\draw[{Arc Barb[]}-{Bracket[]}, ultra thick, red!70!black] (0.6,.02) -- (1,0.02);
\draw[{Arc Barb[length=10pt,width=30pt]}-{Bracket[length=10pt,width=30pt]}, ultra thick, red!70!black] (0,.02) -- (0.4,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad english, I'm from vzla, here one code that I use to my work with intervals:

```
\documentclass{article,11pt,letterpaper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns,patterns.meta} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[>=latex] 
\draw [line width=0.7pt][<->](-0.5,0)--(7,0); 
\end{scope}
\draw [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]},pattern color=blue,line width=0.6pt](4,0)--(4,0.5)--(5,0.5)--(5,0)--cycle;
\draw [pattern={Lines[angle=135,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]},pattern color=red,line width=0.6pt](1,0)--(1,0.5)--(4.5,0.5)--(4.5,0)--cycle;
\fill [color=black](4,0.5) circle (2.3pt); 
\fill [color=white,draw=black,line width=0.7pt] (5,0.5) circle (2.3pt);
\fill [color=white,draw=black,line width=0.7pt] (1,0.5) circle (2.3pt);
\fill [color=black] (4.5,0.5) circle (2.3pt); 
\draw [line width=0.7pt](0,-0.05)--(0,0.3);
\pgftext[base,x=0cm,y=-0.3cm,] {\small $0$}; 
\pgftext[base,x=1cm,y=-0.3cm] {\small $1$};
\pgftext[base,x=4cm,y=-0.3cm] {\small $4$};
\pgftext[base,x=4.5cm,y=-0.3cm] {\small $4.5$};
\pgftext[base,x=5cm,y=-0.3cm] {\small $5$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here the result:

[image: Intersection of intervals]

Comment: Thank you for improve the presentation of the answer, Qrrbrbirlbel, https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: So grateful, thank you