# Dibujar intervalos cerrados, abiertos, infinitos

Tags: tikz-pgf

Apenas estoy aprendiendo. ¿Cómo hago intervalos abiertos, la recta real con latex?

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Gracias

```
I'm barely learning. How do I make open intervals, the real line with latex?

I will appreciate your help.

Thank you
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. This site uses english as a common language. Could you translate your question in english?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw open-close interval in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263122/how-to-draw-open-close-interval-in-latex)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263122/how-to-draw-open-close-interval-in-latex